# Concatenate list and int

Tags: python, list, sorting, quicksort

I'm trying to learn python right now and I've come across the quick sort algorithm. This is what I've written so far with example list:
`[3,1,2,2,1,3,6,7,5,4,8]`

```
def quick(self):
    first = self.lst[0]
    l1 = []
    l2 = []
    for item in self.lst[1:]:
        if item <= first:
            l1.append(item)
            print('this is l1:',l1)
        else:
            l2.append(item)
            print('this is l2:', l2)

        return _____
```

I'm trying to do `self.lst = l1 + first + l2`, however when I do so I get an error that states:

```
self.lst = l1 + first + l2
builtins.TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "int") to list
```

I am just trying to get the first pass correct, and maybe implement a `while True until l1 = []` or something.

1. How do I concatenate l1, first and l2 together?
2. What do you guys recommend me do after the first step?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`first` is an `int` while `l1` and `l2` are lists, so if you create a list with `[]` containing a single item (`first`) then you can concatenate the three lists

```
self.lst = l1 + [first] + l2
```

There are [numerous quicksort algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Algorithm) but if we use for example the [Lomuto partition scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Lomuto_partition_scheme) the pseudo-code implementation on Wikipedia is

```
algorithm quicksort(A, lo, hi) is
    if lo < hi then
        p := partition(A, lo, hi)
        quicksort(A, lo, p - 1)
        quicksort(A, p + 1, hi)

algorithm partition(A, lo, hi) is
    pivot := A[hi]
    i := lo        // place for swapping
    for j := lo to hi - 1 do
        if A[j] ≤ pivot then
            swap A[i] with A[j]
            i := i + 1
    swap A[i] with A[hi]
    return i
```

In Python this would look something like

```
def quicksort(A, lo, hi):
    if lo < hi:
        p = partition(A, lo, hi)
        quicksort(A, lo, p-1)
        quicksort(A, p+1, hi)

def partition(A, lo, hi):
    pivot = A[hi]
    i = lo
    for j in range(lo, hi):
        if A[j] <= pivot:
            A[i], A[j] = A[j], A[i]
            i += 1
    A[i], A[hi] = A[hi], A[i]
    return i
```

Testing this implementation

```
>>> lst = [3,1,2,2,1,3,6,7,5,4,8]
>>> quicksort(lst, 0, len(lst)-1)
>>> lst
[1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

Answer (score 0):

quicksort is recursive, so **before** you concatenate, you should pass l1 and l2 to quick (although it looks like you're making it a method of some custom list-style class, so you should make l1 and l2 instances of that class, then call l1.quick()), the return l1 + [first] + l2

Answer (score 0):

Cory has addressed your first question. As for your second, you need to check that the list has at least one element before you start to partition it. And once it's partitioned then you need to recurse on each of `l1` and `l2`. You need to get those sub lists sorted before you concatenate them.

It appears that your `quick` is a method of a class. Sure, you *can* do that if you want, but it's not necessary.